# SendBroadcast not working

Tags: android

I am trying to implement custom bradcastreciever. but my when i register it return null in my intent. I don't know what is going wrong here
?

My activity is here

```
private MyReciever mReceiver;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.mReceiver = new MyReciever();
    Intent result=registerReceiver(this.mReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            "com.example.Broadcast"));
    int status = result.getIntExtra("HighScore",0);
    System.out.println(status+"  Yahoo");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        try {               
            if (i == 7) {
                // MyReciever mr=new MyReciever();
                    Intent intent = new intent();               
                intent.setAction("com.example.Broadcast");
                intent.putExtra("HighScore", 1000);
                sendStickyBroadcast(intent);
                break;

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

and Reciever is

```
     public class MyReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //int data= intent.getIntExtra("HighScore",0);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Highest Score", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

I have given permission in android mainfest file

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

It will return `null` because nothing will have been broadcast for that action yet by the time you call `registerReceiver()`.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendStickyBroadcast%28android.content.Intent%29 "Perform a sendBroadcast(Intent) that is "sticky," meaning the Intent you are sending stays around after the broadcast is complete, so that others can quickly retrieve that data through the return value of registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter). In all other ways, this behaves the same as sendBroadcast(Intent). 

"

Comment: @user2130718: The documentation does not say that Android has a time machine. You are calling `registerReceiver()` **BEFORE** calling `sendStickyBroadcast()`.

Comment: Its okay but before sending stickybroadcast we need first register it. What is good way ?

Comment: @user2130718: Well, the "good way" is to not use sticky broadcasts. I would guess that less than 1 app in 1000 needs them. Beyond that, you are welcome to call `registerReceiver()` first, but you need to have logic in your code that handles a `null` return from `registerReceiver()`.

Comment: I need to do this by stickybroadcast. It want to implement it by using sticky broadcast. According to doc when it will return intent. I need a example for this.

Answer (score -1):

Declare your receiver in the manifest file

```
<receiver
        android:name=".MyReceiver"

    </receiver>
```

Comment: I think I have registered it dynamically so no need to define in mainfest file